# Enzyme simulate returning zero nodes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am using Jest and Enzyme to test my react components. One of the test looks like this:

```
import DropDown from './DropdDown';
import SelectButton from './SelectButton';
import { mount } from "enzyme";

describe('Test Dropdown component', () => {

    it('Check if handleSubmit is called on click', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(
            <DropDown
                data={dropdDownData}
            />);

        expect(wrapper.contains(SelectButton)).toBe(true); // passes
        wrapper.find(SelectButton).at(0).simulate('click');
    })

})
```

I get the following error on running above test:

`Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.`

If `SelectButton` exists in `wrapper`, then why is the node not found in next statement?

It may be noted that `DropDown` renders `SelectWrapper`, which in turn renders `SelectButton`. But this should not make a difference as I am using `mount`?

Comment: Shouldn't at begin with 0? ```wrapper.find(SelectButton).at(0).simulate('click');```

Comment: Replacing `1` with `0` gives the same error. Even removing `at(0)` completely gives the same error. Have changed the code in question.

Comment: could you try `console.log(wrapper.debug())` to see what is actually being rendered?

Comment: Also could you try `wrapper.find('SelectButton').simulate('click');`?

Comment: @acesmndr: Doesn't work. Gives the same error.

Comment: @SerShubham `console.log(wrapper.debug())` doesn't show `SelectButton` anywhere. Not sure why this is happening? Because it's not a direct child of `DropDown`? But then I have used `mount`, not `shallow`. Also, not sure why `expect(wrapper.contains(SelectButton)).toBe(true)` works in this case? I see `<Component />` at a lot of places in the output, although I don't have any component named `Component`.

Comment: Could you please add a link to a demo. I’ll try debugging :)

Answer (score 1):

```
wrapper.find(SelectButton).at(1)
```

is a zero-based collection, **.at(1)** would return an empty wrapper if the collection contains zero or one elements. **.at(0)** should work.